# how to post and update schema within schema array and print it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, populate

Hello i am new to node js and mongoose
i have two schemes and i want to have schema object within the other schema
 my schemes

user.js

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Genre = require('../Models/genre');

// create a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true , index:true},
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  age: String,
  gender: String,
  genres: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: Genre.Genre}] //this is the genre schema - the user can have many genres
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;
```

also have tried to do

```
genres: [{type: Schema.Type.ObjectId, ref: Genre.Genre}]
and genres: ['Genre']
```

and genre.js

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// create a schema
var genreSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
  age: String,
  gender: String
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var Genre = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

// make this available to our genres in our Node applications
module.exports = Genre;
```

first i want to know if its the way to do that? there is better way?

when i post user by postman the user is adding but i dont get the full genre and i dont know if its saved right

this is the json i post

```
{
"name":"erez",
"age": "23",
"password":"erez1234",
"email":"erez@erez.com",
"gender":"Male",
"genres": ["57285fe32c3c15e40c000001"] /// what should be here? is it right?
}
```

and this is the get users json

```
[
  {
    "_id": "572874be9b43cb4834000002",
    "name": "erez",
    "age": "23",
    "password": "yaniv1234",
    "email": "erez@beatman.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "__v": 0,
    "genres": [
      "57285fe32c3c15e40c000001"
    ]
  }
]
```

if its right
how i can send the full user with all genres on a get users?

hope i am clear enough

thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the references, the `ref` attribute must match exactly the model name in your model definition else you will get an error. The `ref` value should be a string, not an object as you have done, so the correct way should be

```
genres: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre'}]
```

When you are reading the data, Mongoose population makes reads of documents very straightforward through its **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** function. So for instance, to show the referenced genres for a particular user, call the **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** method with the name of that field in a string as a parameter e.g.

```
User.findOne({"name": "Tom"})
    .populate("genres")
    .exec(err, user) { ... }
```

Comment: so the post user i do is correct? and can i do populate for all users? or only by findone? can also done by findById function??

Comment: Yes, the way you are writing the data is correct. As with the reading part, any of the `find()` or `findOne()` methods can chain the `populate()` function, I simply gave the findOne as an example. This can be extended to the `find()` method as well if you want to populate for all users.

Comment: User.find()
  .populate("genres")
  .exec(function (err, users) { 
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

   res.json(users);
        }); ---- function that works for all users